# About Repository Update Automatic

Tags: github, version-control, repository, gitlab

Since yesterday, I was thinking about this.

I imported my object from gitlab to github, if I update my repository in gitlab, is my repository in github updated because I update my repository in github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repository in GitHub would not be updated if you updated your repository in GitLab unless you have [Repository Mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html) active, where you have set up push rules to the GitHub repository.

Note, that you need to have GitLab Starter/Bronze edition to use Repository Mirroring.